# System.ArgumentException "Parameter is not valid" when comparing image dimensions

Tags: c#, parameters, argumentexception

I have a C# WinForms app in which the following line throws an exception:

```
if (glbQuestion.imgQuestionImage.Size.Height > glbQuestion.imgQuestionImage.Size.Width)
```

The exception is "System.ArgumentException/Parameter is not valid." The image is not null and its dimensions are Width=299xHeight=422. Apart from the image being null, what else could cause this and what would be a better way to write it?

Comment: can you log the glbQuestion.imgQuestionImage.Size.Height and glbQuestion.imgQuestionImage.Size.Width in console and able to  see value

Comment: Is there a Width and Height property on Image object directly instead of Size? like imgQuestionImage.Width?

Comment: The full stack trace of the exception should show you what call is throwing it.

Comment: best is to  debug.write these variables

Comment: Please also include the image part of the code.